# The diagonals $\Delta=\{(v,v)\mid v\in V\}$ is transversal to $W=\{v,Av\mid v\in V\}$ iff $+1$ is not an eigenvalue of A

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

Learning Differential topology, Sorry for asking anything trivial. I am stuck in this question:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $\Delta$ be the diagonal of $V \times V$ . For a linear map $A : V \to V$ consider the graph $W = \{(v, Av) \in V \times V \}$. Show that $W \pitchfork \Delta$($W$ transversal to $\Delta$) if and only if $+1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

My attempt:

So, $\Delta \cap W=\{(v,v) \mid Av=v\}.$ If +1 is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\det(A-I)=0$ which implies $A-I$ has rank less than $n$. So, for $A-I:V \to V$, the derivative at any point $p\in V$ is zero that is, $D(A-I)(p)=0$ which implies $D(A-I)$ is not surjective at any point $p\in V$. So, $p$ is a critical point of $A-I$. but then how can I use it to conclude that $\Delta$ is not transverse to $W$?

For the other way, suppose $+1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\Delta\cap W=\{(0,0)\}$, as $Av=v\implies v=0$(because 1 isn't an eigenvalue). So, $\Delta$ and $W$ intersects only at $(0,0)$. And hence they are transversal being no intersecting tangentially. Is that a correct argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the work you have done, you can prove both implications simultaneously. You already showed that
$$
\Delta\cap W=\{(v,v):Av=v\}=\{(v,v):v\in\text{Ker}(A-I)\}.
$$
So we get
\begin{align}
W\pitchfork\Delta & \Leftrightarrow W+\Delta=V\times V\\
&\Leftrightarrow W\cap\Delta=\{(0,0)\} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \text{Ker}(A-I)=\{0\}\\
&\Leftrightarrow A-I \ \text{is invertible}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \det(A-I)\neq 0\\
&\Leftrightarrow 1\ \text{is no eigenvalue of}\ A.
\end{align}

Comment: But why $W \cap \Delta$ must equals to $\{(0,0)\}$? Why couldn't this intersection be any sigle point?

Comment: ahhh!! Because $(0,0)$ must be in the $Ker(A - I)$.. hahahahha